# NLP Aspect Mining approach

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to implement as aspect miner based on consumer reviews in amazon for durable- washing machine, refrigerator. The idea is to output sentiment polarity for aspects instead of the entire sentence. For eg: 'Food was good but service was bad' review must output food to be positive and service to be negative. I read through Richard Socher's paper on RNTN model for fine grained sentiment classifier but I guess I'll need to manually tag sentiment for phrases for a different domain and create my own treebank for better accuracy.

Here's an alternate approach I'd thought of. Could someone pls validate/guide me with your feedback
Break the approach into 2 sub tasks. 1) Identify aspects 2) Identify sentiment

**Identify aspects**

1. Use POS tagger to identify all nouns. This should shortlist
   potentially all aspects in the reviews.
2. Use word2vec of these nouns to determine similar nouns and reduce the dataset size

**Identify sentiments**

3. Train a CNN or dense net model on reviews with rating 1,2,4,5(ignore
   3 as we need data that has polarity)
4. Breakdown the test set reviews into phrases(eg 'Food was good') and then score them using the above model
5. Find the aspects identified in the 1st sub task and tag them to
   their respective phrases.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019446/identifying-multiple-categories-and-associated-sentiment-within-text/45025107#45025107

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifying multiple categories and associated sentiment within text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019446/identifying-multiple-categories-and-associated-sentiment-within-text)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to answer this question but have a few suggestions:

1. Take a look at multitask learning in neuralnets literature and try an end2end neuralnet for multiple tasks.
2. Use pretrained word vectors like w2v or glov as inputs.
3. Don't rely on pos taggers when you use internet data,
4. Find a way to represent your name entities and oov in your design.
5. Don't ignore 3!!
6. You should annotate some data periodically.